# How to get list of printer on Android with PrinterDiscoverySession?

Tags: java, android, printing

How can I retrieve a list of available printers on android with using PrinterDiscoverySession class?

Any code snippets will greatly be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not available using Android APIs. Only the system can query installed and enabled Print Services.